# Drop external table in Azure Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-managed-instance

We moved a database from on-prem to Azure Managed Instance. But now we can't use External Tables, so we're taking a different approach. Is there a way to drop the external tables so I can use the object names for local tables?

If I run the normal instruction

```
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[MyExternalTable]
```

It shows the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.

If I run the command to drop like a normal table, I get a different error mentioning that this is an external table.

```
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MyExternalTable]
```

It shows the error

> Msg 3705, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'dbo.MyExternalTable' because 'dbo.MyExternalTable' is a EXTERNAL TABLE. Use DROP EXTERNAL TABLE.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try just `drop table dbo.MyExternalTable`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. I tried it and it didn't work, either.

Comment: I edited the question to address that before I wrote the comment, @J.D.

Comment: Sorry I must've missed your post update, or it was just a timing thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with on-premises, solved with :

```
exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1;
reconfigure
```

Comment: It is best to explain your answer so that it is obvious to everyone that it is correct.